# postgres is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported

Tags: postgresql

If the error occurs when trying to create PostgreSql Role This error occurs because you are inside the postgresql.

You need to change to root user, for that you need to type in the terminal,

**su root**

Next run the command,
**sudo -u postgres createuser --interactive**

Answer (score 2):

Your question is hard to follow, as it reads like you are just quoting someone else, but it isn't clear who or why.

The way this usually happens to me is that initially I am logged in as a user who does have sudo powers (my normal daily user account), but then I change into "postgres" Linux user by executing `sudo su - postgres`.  But once there, I then try to execute some sudo command, but since logged in as postgres and postgres does not have sudo powers, I get this error.  I fix the error by exiting the shell which is logged in as postgres, and so dropping back to my regular account, before repeating the sudo attempt.

Answer (score 0):

su root
nano /etc/sudoers
Then add the user below admin user like below syntax.
user_name ALL=(ALL)  ALL
Save the changes in nano by pressing Ctrl+O, and then exit nano by pressing Ctrl+X